# Clickhouse Materialised view is not triggered

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse, materialized-views

I created a table that reads the kafka topic with JSONAsString format

```
CREATE TABLE tracking_log_kafka_raw
(
    jsonString String
) ENGINE = Kafka
      SETTINGS
          kafka_broker_list = 'kafka:9092',
          kafka_topic_list = 'tracking_log_new',
          kafka_group_name = 'test_1',
          kafka_format = 'JSONAsString';
```

Final table

```
CREATE TABLE k_t_res
(
    jsonString String
) ENGINE = MergeTree()
      ORDER BY jsonString
      SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192;
```

And materialized view

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test_c TO k_t_res
AS
SELECT *
FROM tracking_log_kafka_raw;
```

But when I write to kafka, the messages get into the *tracking_log_kafka_raw* table, but they are not triggered mat view , so nothing gets into the final *k_t_res* table.

I tried using JSONEachRow format and everything worked, but the message format in kafka doesn't allow it to be used.

Comment: There should be entries in the error logs, if you demonstrate them this will greatly help solving the problem. The path should be like `/ var / log / clickhouse-server / clickhouse-server.err.log`

Comment: I watched the logs while writing to the kafka, there were no errors.
There are errors related to connection timeout:
```{} <Warning> StorageKafka (tracking_log_kafka_raw): [rdk:MAXPOLL] [thrd:main]: Application maximum poll interval (300000ms) exceeded by 45ms (adjust max.poll.interval.ms for long-running message processing): leaving group```

Comment: Well, since the message gets into the table with the Kafka engine, then there will be no errors when reading kafka. Obviously there are errors when transferring from this table to `k_t_res`, most likely the field types are not compatible and on the side of the materialized view it is necessary to cast types.

Comment: It sounds good, but I don't understand why the types are not compatible, String is specified everywhere. Also I tried using ```JSONExtractString(jsonString, 'guid')``` which return string field

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the version of clickhouse used. Initially used 21.9.4.35, after switching to 20.10.6.27 everything worked